Split a page with multiple physical photos into separate entities
I have A4-sized scanned pages, some of them containing multiple photos per sheet (they are actual physical photos of a smaller than A4 size) separated with blank paddings. As it is not originally digital images, this blank paddings may not be digital pure white and they may contain some noise and slight variations of white color.
I need to split those sheets into a bunch of separate photos for further prrocessing.
Is there a tool, that could automatically do so? Maybe it could be done with ImageMagick, then where to look.
P.S. Images are TIFF and output should be TIFF as well or any other loseless format.
